# Getting the sum of column grouped by date

Tags: mysql, sql

Was wondering if there is a way to get the sum of the stock_case column for items with the same date_of_export ?

Updated with fiddle here and some relevant data:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/szC1Ftj3ZGEC24gSYp6ad4/4

The expected output would be this:

[image]
This is the query used

```
    SELECT 
    st.product_code,
    st.date_of_export,
    st.best_before_date,
    st.stock_case,
    (
    SELECT 
            SUM(st2.stock_case)
        FROM
            stock_tracking AS st2
            WHERE
            st2.product_code IN ('MGN003')
        AND MONTH(st2.date_of_export) IN (07)
        AND YEAR(st2.date_of_export) IN (2018)
        AND st2.stock_case != 0
    ) AS total
    FROM
    stock_tracking st
WHERE
    product_code IN ('MGN003')
        AND MONTH(st.date_of_export) IN (07)
        AND YEAR(st.date_of_export) IN (2018)
        AND stock_case != 0
```

and my results
[image]

Would like to have a total column like 16, 16, 16, ... , 19, etc
For another case I used a subquery like so

```
SELECT 
    d.products_name,
    stock_case,
    st.date_of_export,
    st.best_before_date,
    st.product_code,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(st2.stock_case)
        FROM
            stock_tracking AS st2
        WHERE
            DATE(st2.date_of_export) = (SELECT 
                    DATE(tmp.last_update)
                FROM
                    (SELECT 
                        date_of_export AS last_update
                    FROM
                        stock_tracking
                    ORDER BY date_of_export DESC
                    LIMIT 1) AS tmp
                WHERE
                    product_code = 'MGN003')) AS total
FROM
    stock_tracking st
        LEFT JOIN
    products AS p ON p.products_model = st.product_code
        LEFT JOIN
    products_description AS d ON d.products_id = p.products_id
WHERE
    product_code = 'MGN003'
        AND d.language_id = 2
        AND DATE(st.date_of_export) = (SELECT 
            DATE(tmp.last_update)
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                date_of_export AS last_update
            FROM
                stock_tracking AS st
            ORDER BY date_of_export DESC
            LIMIT 1) AS tmp)
```

with this result:
[image]

Comment: Could you please add sample input and expected output with table structures ?

Comment: My, that's a lot of cider (well, perry). To clarify, what is the actual desired result?

Comment: Hello , the result would be similar with the last image where the total ( sum of stock_case) is calculated for each row where the date of export is the same. So 'マグナーズ　ペアー 330ml 瓶 x 24本', '14', '2018-07-09 00:00:00', '2018-05-31 00:00:00', 'MGN003', 16

Comment: I would suggest you see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - I would write the Magner's Pear bit in English, to avoid unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Hey you are right. Updated the question with a relevant fiddle containing all concerned schema and some test data.

Comment: So, can you just clarify again what the result set should look like - Note: update your question accordingly.

Comment: It's better - but there's still so much irrelevant data, it makes it really hard to see how the tables relate. Are you able to remove everything that's not actually relevant to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a subquery to `sum(stock_case)`  by `date_of_export`, then `self join` on `Date`, then you can get your expect result.

```
SELECT  
    s.product_name,
    s.date_of_export,
    s.best_before_date,
    s.product_code,
    s.stock_case,
    t.totle
FROM
    stock_tracking s
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT SUM(stock_case) totle,date_of_export dt
       FROM stock_tracking
       where   
        product_code = 'MGN003'
        AND MONTH(date_of_export) =07
        AND YEAR(date_of_export) =2018
        AND stock_case != 0
      GROUP BY date_of_export
    ) t on DATE_FORMAT(s.date_of_export, "%d-%m-%Y") = DATE_FORMAT(t.dt, "%d-%m-%Y")
where 
    s.product_code = 'MGN003'
AND MONTH(s.date_of_export) =07
AND YEAR(s.date_of_export) =2018
AND s.stock_case != 0
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/szC1Ftj3ZGEC24gSYp6ad4/6)

Answer (score -1):

Without giving you the exact answer: You should think in the direction of:

```
SELECT SUM(column) FROM table WHERE ... GROUP BY date
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(column), DISTINCT date FROM table WHERE ...
```

So lookup the way GROUP BY and DISTINCT work :-)

Comment: Yep, because DISTINCT and SUM would never normally appear in the same query together.

Comment: giving a correct hint in stead of the typed out copy/paste solution is downvoted nowadays? Have a look at the accepted answer...